# rails 3.2.19 is it possible to call a view without an integer id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes

As far i know when calling the show view you usually have an id which is a number(1234) but what if that id is a path (clips/2010/03/19/3591/fnc-201)?
is it doable?

**update**

I need to explain more...
When i type `http://10.1.4.167:3003/embed/` i want to add `1234` or `clips/2010/03/19/3591/fnc-201` to the url (and get `http://10.1.4.167:3003/embed/1234` or `http://10.1.4.167:3003/embed/clips/2010/03/19/3591/fnc-201`) then i can use that url do some transformations on the value and then query (or not) the DB with the transformed value.

So the value is not from the DB initially...

Now i get `No route matches [GET] "http://10.1.4.167:3003/embed/clips/2010/03/19/3591/fnc-201"`

Anything i can do in the routes.rb file?

Comment: Do you want `2010/03/19/3591/fnc-201` to be a part of url path?

Comment: Related but different...have you looked at the https://github.com/norman/friendly_id gem?

Comment: @blelump: yes. since the id can be id like `http://10.1.4.167:3003/embed/200482` or a path like `http://10.1.4.167:3003/embed/clips/2010/03/19/3591/fnc-201`

Comment: You need something like @BobMazanec suggested, cause your url in such format is invalid.

Comment: ok, thanks. Is there anything non ActiveRecord related?

Comment: Check here: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_permalinks___slugs , perhaps any of those gems will meet your requirements.

Comment: thanks but they all are linked to active directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

going back to the [roots](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) i found what  i were looking for:

```
get '*embed', to: 'embed#show', format: false
```

Hope it helps someone

PS:
make sure to put it all the way down on your route.rb file as it is a more "complex route"